# Equivalent of CakePHP $this->params to retrieve all POST/GET on Yii?

Tags: cakephp, yii, parameters

On CakePHP we can get ALL POST/GET using

```
$this->params
```

On Yii, I am not sure if it has a equivalent. Only saw if I want to get one field value regardless if (POST/GET), but I need to specify it.

```
Yii::app()->request->getParam('email')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Yii it's perfectly fine to use `$_REQUEST` , `$_POST` , `$_GET` directly.

What `getParam` really does is use those arrays directly anyway, but with the difference that if the *param* doesn't exist it returns `null` by default, or a value that you specify as the second argument to the `getParam` call:

[Source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L158):

```
public function getParam($name,$defaultValue=null)
{
    return isset($_GET[$name]) ? $_GET[$name] : (isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : $defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: How about sanitizing when using $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST? My understand is when using getParam, it sanitize those data and that will be useful.

Comment: i have already posted the `getParam` source code in the answer, you should be able to see that there is no sanitizing happening there. sanitization is taken care of differently in yii, but not in `getParam`. how that is handled is vast, there are tips in [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security), and for [database](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.overview)